# Is $V=S\oplus T$ if and only if $S\times T\ni(v,w)\mapsto v+w\in V$ is a vector space isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum

**Definition** (direct sum): If $S$ and $T$ are vector subspaces of $V$, we write $V=S\oplus T$ if $S\cap T=\{0\}$ and $\{v+w:v\in S,w\in T\}=V$.

Thus, if $V=S\oplus T$,
\begin{align}
\phi\colon S\times T&\to V\\
(v,w)&\mapsto v+w
\end{align}
is a vector space isomorphism.

Conversely, can we show that $V=S\oplus T$ if $\phi$ is a vector space isomorphism? That is, can we prove $S\cap T=\{0\}$, possibly without assuming that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: yes the fact that the intersection is the zero subspace is equivalent to injectivity of the function, and the fact the sum of subspaces is $V$ is equivalent to surjectivity of your map.

Comment: In you definition you have written $S\cap   T=\emptyset$ and must mean $\{0\}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo If $v\in S\cap T$, $\phi(v,v)=v+v=(v+v)+0=\phi(v+v,0)$. If $\phi$ is injective, this implies $v+v=v$ and $v=0$. Is that the proof you had in mind?

Comment: @Filippo sure, that works, but what I had in mind is that if $v\in S\cap T$, then $v=\phi(v,0)=\phi(0,v)$, so $(0,v)=(v,0)$ by injectivity hence $v=0$... but of course yours is also fine.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Lol, now that I saw your proof it seems so obvious - thank you for sharing your (much nicer) proof :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $S\cap T=\{0\}$ if and only if
\begin{align}
\phi\colon S\times T&\to V\\
(v,w)&\mapsto v+w
\end{align}
is injective. (Reminder: $S\cap T$ is a vector subspace of $V$, because the intersection of vector subspaces is a vector subspace.)

**Proof**.

- If $v\in S\cap T$, $\phi(v,0)=\phi(0,v)$ and if, in addition, $\phi$ is injective,
  \begin{equation}
  \phi(v,0)=\phi(0,v)\Leftrightarrow (v,0)=(0,v)\Leftrightarrow v=0.
  \end{equation}
- Conversely, if $S\cap T=\{0\}$ and $(v,w),(v',w')\in S\times T$, then
  \begin{equation}
  \phi(v,w)=\phi(v',w')\Leftrightarrow v+w=v'+w'\Leftrightarrow v-v'=w'-w=:u.
  \end{equation}
  Since $v-v'\in S$ and $w'-w\in T$, $u\in S\cap T=\{0\}$. Thus, $v=v'$ and $w=w'$.